# pandas keep a string in a column with some values as datetime but others are not datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to transform a string column to datetime format in pandas data framework.
But, some values in the column are strings.
e.g.

```
id      a_date_time
1       5/12/2010
2       6/19/2011
3       pending
4       in progress
```

For, the correct datetime format, I can transform it to datetime. 
But, for string type, I also need to keep them because they also carry some information for the further work of prediction.

My code:

```
 my_df['a_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(self.__df['a_date_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

does not work for this case.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I understand that this is not really a technical problem, but more about semantics. I will give you my solution to this, but this is a subjective way of thinking.

Comment: I would separate out this data into two columns titled "date" and "progress-state". The dates can be converted using `pd.to_datetime`. All rows with a date can be marked as "complete" in the progress-status column. All rows without a date can be filled with None or "null" values.

Comment: In my experience better semantics leads to better datatypes and better compression on disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (correctly) use paralleled operations if your series is mixed type. Try apply: `df.a_date_time.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='ignore'))`.